# Facebook fan page iframe tab links not opening in the iframe

Tags: facebook

I have a basic facebook iframe application that sits inside a fan page tab.  All i want to do is have the links in my application open inside of the iframe.  I tried to change their target to _self but no sauce, all of the links open in a new window.  The application is [here](http://www.facebook.com/LovingPets?v=app_19827163485#!/LovingPets)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the target="_blank" attribute from the links.

Btw, that's not an iframe application.  Looks like a static FBML tab app.

Comment: I actually don't have any _blank targets in my code.  It appears facebook has added that automatically?  You were right about it being a FBML tab application i forgot to update the settings.  I changed my Page Tab Type setting from FBML to iframe but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: any one have an answer? ive posted on almost 10 forums and blogs but still haven't gotten an answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding target="_top"